# How to force many-to-many filter direction using intermediate table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm making a PowerBI dashboard to view loans and their relevant security items. My relationships are not filtering appropriately to show only the security items which are linked to the relevant account.

Each account can have multiple security items, and each security item can be on multiple accounts (though only one account will be open). Each Item is attached I have set up the tables as:

```
TABLE: Accounts
- pk
- Status

TABLE: SecStmtItemAcc
- Pk
- AcctPK
- SecStmtPk

TABLE SecurityStatementItem
- Pk
- SecStmtPk
- ExpiryDate
```

The Relationships are:

Many-to-one: SecStmtItemAcc to SecurityStatementItem

Many-to-one: SecStmtItemAcc to Accounts

I wanted to put this into a report table to show only the Items which are linked to the account e.g.

```
Account | Item
 12     |  A
 15     |  B
 15     |  D
```

Instead I get every Item marked against every account:

```
Account | Item
 12     |  A
 12     |  B
 12     |  D
```

Comment: You can set your filter direction for the relationship to both. Or create a measure that enforces it to both with the dax function CROSSFILTER

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show Account and related Item PK in with no measures, just illustrated in the question?

In that case, putting `SecStmtItemAcc[SecStmtPk]` instead of `SecurityStatementItem[Pk]` would just work.

If you want to show additional `SecurityStatementItem` attributes like `ExpiryDate`, you can create calculated column in `SecStmtItemAcc` table to append that attributes, like `RELATED(SecurityStatementItem[ExpiryDate])`, and use it in the report.

If you need some measures on `SecurityStatementItem` such as `MIN(SecurityStatementItem[ExpiryDate])` and align it with `Accounts`, then you can use `CROSSFILTER()`. For example,

```
EarliestExpiryDate :=
CALCULATE(
    MIN(SecurityStatementItem[ExpiryDate]),
    CROSSFILTER(SecStmtItemAcc[ItemPk], SecurityStatementItem[Pk], BOTH)
)
```